Omnipay Paypal php issue - adding multiple items to checkout
I'd like to be able to pass multiple items with their details through an associative array as shown in the following code:
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    try {
        $response = $gateway->purchase([
            'amount'=>'60.00',
            'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:3000/success.php',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:3000/cancel.php'
        ])->setItems(array(
            array('name' => 'item1', 'quantity' => 2, 'price' => '10.00'),
            array('name' => 'item2', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => '50.00')
        ))->send();

        if ($response->isRedirect()) {
            $response->redirect(); // this will automatically forward the customer
        } else {
            // not successful
            echo $response->getMessage();
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

?>

And my response file code looks like this:
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
 
// Once the transaction has been approved, we need to complete it.
if (array_key_exists('paymentId', $_GET) && array_key_exists('PayerID', $_GET)) {
    $transaction = $gateway->completePurchase(array(
        'payer_id'             => $_GET['PayerID'],
        'transactionReference' => $_GET['paymentId'],
    ));
    $response = $transaction->send();
 
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        // The customer has successfully paid.
        $arr_body = $response->getData();
 
        $payment_id = $db->real_escape_string($arr_body['id']);
        $payer_id = $db->real_escape_string($arr_body['payer']['payer_info']['payer_id']);
        $payer_email = $db->real_escape_string($arr_body['payer']['payer_info']['email']);
        $amount = $db->real_escape_string($arr_body['transactions'][0]['amount']['total']);
        $currency = PAYPAL_CURRENCY;
        $payment_status = $db->real_escape_string($arr_body['state']);
 
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO payments(payment_id, payer_id, payer_email, amount, currency, payment_status) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $payment_id, $payer_id, $payer_email, $amount, $currency, $payment_status);
        $db->query($sql);
 
        echo "Payment is successful. Your transaction id is: ". $payment_id;
    } else {
        echo $response->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Transaction is declined';
}


?>

I'd like for the buyer to be able to see all items that they're about to purchase, along with their total cost. What exactly is the issue?
I tried the code above and the result is an error as shown below:
"Invalid request - see details"

And the details are?

what are you asking? If you know Omnipay, you should understand what I'm asking with the two files mentioned.

The error states "see details" what are those details, or are there none - that's what Preston is asking.
